# Coordinates not printing when the simulator is run, but they are when I run the program on my iPhone

Tags: swift, core-location, cllocationmanager

I have the following code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var coordinates: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }


func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    //updates the user's location as the user moves
    let location: CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation
    coordinates = "\(location.coordinate.latitude),\(location.coordinate.longitude)"
    print(coordinates!)
}
```

When I run this on the simulator, the program works fine but it doesn't print the coordinates. When I run it on my iPhone, it prints the coordinates. Is there something in the Xcode settings I need to change to fix this? Also, when I try to use the "coordinates" variable in another function, I get an error saying the compiler is finding nil even though I assigned it a value in the locationManager function, so I'm guessing the two problems are connected. Thanks in advance

Comment: uninstall in simulator and install again

Comment: Odd, that partially works. Prints a few times but stops when it's supposed to keep going. Thanks dude

Comment: How would the simulator know where you are?

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate location on the simulator using "Simulate location" button when running your app:

[image]

You can select one of the existing locations or you can create a GPX file (for example not a static single point but a route that will simulate constant changing of location). I would recommend you using https://mapstogpx.com/ to create GPX files.